# one asp.net web application with multiple projects to develop as a team, easy update !

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, iis-7, gac

i want to design an asp.net application to be worked from multiple projects,

i have used web application projects in visual studio
and make every part of application in one project compiled in one dll.

the problem is how can make it in IIS with a way allow me and my friends (developers) to work in his own project without stopping or make others work slow when make build
because the build will be in same bin to be worked all in one application

i thought in run bin folder outside website or multi bin folders 
but failed to make this

also thought to make it in IIS virtual directory for every part or application to use its own bin, but also never use its own bin folder especially in convert virtual directory to application.

i tried to add dll to GAC but i found problems in update dll, will cause restart all iis, and this will restart all work as i do not want ...

so kindly, if any one here have an advice to me

**UPDATE**

i am using url rewrite so i am loading usercontrols from virtual directory or application not loading direct aspx files, and when doing that not loading bin inside virtual directory or application

**UPDATE 2**

Thanks for comments, and According to that;
to split projects may work in virtual application inside IIS7, and each virtual application will work with its own bin, but each virtual application (project) only have usercontrols and we are using urlrewrite, so when load usercontrol and url not include the virsual application path, its required bin from root not from virtual application

**My Regards**

Comment: Have you considered using ASP.NET MVC since it has built in support for **areas**?

Comment: we are using vs2010 but still some projects build for .net framework 2.0, i thought to make it web service or WCF,but as i will update question, that every project only have usercontrols and dynamically loaded in only on aspx page, so kindly if you have any more information can help me in ASP.NET MVC, thanks to tell me, Thanks a lot for your comment

Comment: i have no ideas about ASP.NET MVC, could you tell me or a link, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you are ALL developing against one central server, which would be my first piece of advice:

```
Each developer develops against a local dev server, not production
```

Use some kind of distributed source control ([Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/)) which allows teams of developers to commit and branch easily.

I would explicitly advise you to NOT have you and your friends all mucking around in your running server while you are developing. Use local dev servers for development, then deploy to production when you are ready for a push.

**UPDATE**:

It sounds like a virtual application host name and edit to hosts file **might** help. Try this:

- When you set up your app in IIS, give it a hostname as well as a physical path and name. Something similar to **www.myapp.localdev**, this way it is blatently obvious that you're in your dev environment.
- If working on windows, open \System32\drivers\etc\hosts and add the following line:

  ```
  127.0.0.1       www.myapp.localdev
  ```

Now, any requests to www.myapp.localdev will be redirected to your localhost, which will resolve with your local instance of IIS. Since you've configured your virtual app with this hostname, your app **should** be listening for these requests. Beyond that, you will have to configure your app to run locally, but this should at least get you going on that path.

Comment: first thanks, the application we are working in, all is usercontrols and loaded dynamically in only one aspx page in the main project, and not one can build his own project alone he can not test it except from the main application or main url, and working in save local server and every one work in his usercontrols or project, so is there any ideas to do that with this situation, Thanks again

Comment: @BMTS Nobody is able to build his own project alone?  Why not?  Developers **need** to be able to build and test their changes in isolation in order to be able to work efficiently.

Comment: every one can build his own project normally, but can not test it because there is not pages at all, all usercontrols and loaded dynamically, so how can i allow them to build without cause app restart for others due to change in bin folder, thanks for reply

Comment: @BMTU my idea for that situation would be to rewrite it so you CAN work and test locally. There's no reason you should NOT be able to do that.

Comment: @KG Thanks for reply, i am already using urlrewrite but the virtual application contains only usercontrols, when i load usercontrol it's load bin from root not from bin under virtual application, and may the solution to run eache virtual application (project) from it's own bin but its a problem with url rewrite, Thanks Again

Comment: @BMTU WHY is it a problem with URL Rewrite? You can point your local hosts file to the domains that you set up your application to run from locally (i.e. production is app.com, local is app.localdev or something similar). This way your URL Rewrites do not break. If you have external services required, you can run those on local machine or in a virtual machine, if necessary.

Comment: @KG Thanks for reply, the url rewrite is working good, but when loading usercontrol placed in virtual directory it's required dll code of usercontrol to be in bin of root not bin inside virtual directory, and it's fact, it's the current situation, you try to load usercontrol from virtual directory inside page in root, and see code of usercontrol must be where? thanks again

Comment: @BMTU hmm...I have many virtual applications running on my local IIS7 server that have usercontrols (some ASP.net MVC apps, some webforms apps) that work just fine. When you set up the virtual application, what steps are you taking? There might be some configuration that is not set up properly, which is not far-fetched: IIS can be a pain ;-)

Comment: @KG Just under website add application and type name with physical path and nothing else, and another information for you when using url and page load usercontrol in virtual application, the url not contain the vertual application path ... Thanks

Comment: @BMTU ahhh...ok. Now we're getting somewhere :-) I'll add update to my answer.

Comment: @KG Thanks, running app.local already redrected to 127.0.0.1 but what we are talking about, there is a virtual app /vapp contain uc.ascx when run http://app.local/en/someurl a page will loaded under root will load /vapp/uc.ascx in a placeholder so code of uc.ascx must be under root/bin not /vapp/bin, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a combination of source control and local developer instances.

What you're trying to do isn't unlike what everyone else does. This is how most people do it:

1) Use source control. You can try git at https://github.com/. You need to add your source code to a git project, then all your other developers will be able to stay in sync. It will give you a complete history of every change that takes place and you'll be able to go back to old versions.

Here is a post with references to git: [Introduction to Git and practical usage patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748272/introduction-to-git-and-practical-usage-patterns)

2) All your developers need local instances. Visual Studio can host ASP.NET projects itself. You can also install IIS (And SQL Server if you need). It's very easy to setup and use.

You can find directions on how to use Visual Studio with IIS here: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-7/

By doing these two things, each developer can work independently. Once you're ready, then you push your changes to your production server.

Comment: the main problem is not to know updates of files or last versions, the problem is when one make build will change bin directory and then will cause app restart for all others, and trying to find multi bin folders but outside root app to avoid that, out numbr is not large to use git, thanks a lot for your try ...

Comment: Your developers should not be sharing the same bin directory. Each developer has visual studio with IIS. That means each one has their own bin directory, and no one affects anyone else. The multi bin directory is the wrong way to go. Honestly, it's easier to just set it up properly, or you will forever be fighting your enviornment. Each developer will tell you when it's time to update your versions of the files. When I commit my changes and push them to github, they are now available for you. Once you merge them, our two copies are identical. If I break something, it doesn't break it for you.

Comment: Even single developers use source control such as git. Using source control and using an automated build and deployment server will solve all of your problems. It's sort of the industry standard way of doing things.